# Can't Determine the direction of rotation of a coil

Tags: magnetic-fields, torque

Speaking of coils and torque here,
 So I have a coil and after I did fleming's right hand rule to get the direction of the torque (let it be the positive x-axis unit vector î can't remember it correctly) 
I was asked to get it's direction of rotation: whether it is clockwise or anti-clockwise.
What I tried is handling segments of the coil separately to know the direction of rotation but that didn't help me much as the coil was on xy plane, 
I kept imagining it but I can't figure out if its clockwise or anti I mean it depends whether I look at it from the right or the left, 
I also tried right hand screw rule but It made no sense to me,
 at last I tried to look it up on Internet but didn't really find any results so I head over here in hope I get help.
Thank you
Edit(2):
I am not allowed to post pictures, and not familiar with mathjax I use the app on my phone
 I will try to describe one of the two problems I am talking about:
Rectangular coil of 20 turns and an area of 0.005 square meters, carrying current of 10A, Its hinged along the y-axis and mounted on XY plane at an angle of 30 degrees to a uniform magnetic field of 0.5 tesla, Find the torque vector and the direction of rotation of the coil. 
So the coil has one long side on y and one short side on x (axis) the direction of current is also given 
So tau=NI AxB is what I did after resolution of B into a vector and what I got was 4.33*10^-3 (-y axis unit vector)
But I am struggling with the direction of rotation for the coil

Comment: Pardon me, stack exchange didn't allow me to post photos due reputation I will update with some detailed context.

Comment: Also, please format your question properly and use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write math expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with the [Magnetic Moment Vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment)?

As a thumb rule you can remember that it wants to align itself to the Magnetic Field.

Comment: Yes I do, it's the same as the direction of the torque vector , what exactly is trying to align it self? The coil plane?

Comment: This vector aligns to the magnetic field($\vec B$). You can determine Clockwise or Anticlockwise that way.

Comment: In my case the magnetic field vector has 2 component one with x and another with z so I will align with the one which is parallel to the plane which is with x  and it will seem to rotate clockwise, alright thanks

Comment: @user597368 Please accept this answer if it solved your queries.